# wanted - golang wrapper around Dial/Listen to handle tcp server/client communication

Tags: go, tcp

In golang, when you make a client/server combination with Listen/Accept on the server and Dial on the client, as far as I can tell writing to the client doesn't actually guarantee the full transmission chain. IE when you say:

```
_len, _err := conn.Write([]byte("sent"))
```

it is possible that the text you send may reach the buffer of the client machine but not the client itself. In other words, if the client becomes unavailable, _err may still be unset and _len may still show the correct length of bytes being sent. I noticed this by killing the connection between my server and client and monitoring the return status of conn.Write() manually and seeing that it didn't show an error.

In other words, just using these tools out of the box won't guarantee delivery, and I was hoping that there was a go library that implemented a client acknowledgement to insure this further guarantee. I'd like to say something like:

```
_len, _err := _write(conn, "sent\n")
```

and have guarantees that if the client goes away that _err will be set accordingly - assuming a specific timeout between the send and an acknowledgement from the client.

Is there a standard library like this? I could write my own wrapper to do this, but I have a feeling the logic to do this correctly would be somewhat intricate.

thanks much again for any info,

Ed

Comment: If the underlying connection is tcp and if one side of the connection breaks, the other side will get an error eventually. TCP will ack every message. In the case of a broken connection, there is never a guarantee of how much of the message made it to the client. It is possible that the message was read, but nothing was done for it. You can implement your own ack protocol for that.

Comment: Write on a TCP connection returns when the data is written to the operating system, not when the data written to the wire or received to by the peer.  Use an application-level protocol to ACK the data.

Comment: Muffin Top - exactly, I was hoping to be able to avoid writing an application level protocol to ACK the data - ie: creating an associated channel to read from the client and reading an associated ack message back from it should be something fairly generic - and something that I wouldn't want to implement if there was a standard API out there.

Comment: No channels required.  Client replies with ACK message. Server sets read deadline and reads connection for ACK message after write. It's a few lines of code.

Comment: Muffin Top - ok, pointers to a sample implementation would be greatly appreciated here; again i'm fairly new to go so I have a feeling that you could get this subtly wrong.
thanks much..

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a standard library like this?

There is no standard library for this. How application level acknowledgements are done is specified in the specific application protocol, i.e. a protocol like HTTP (web), SMTP (mail delivery), SIP (VoIP) etc. And this protocol must be spoken in both client and server. There is no way for a client to enforce some application level acknowledgement if it is not part of the protocol specification and the server will not explicitly send it.

Therefore you either need to pick an application protocol which supports the semantics you need and use it on both client and server. Or you need to define your own application protocol which supports the exact semantics you need and implement it yourself on both sides.

Comment: steffen - I get that it is application dependent, but I disagree. There could be an API for this with generic routines for different TCP apps.
A simple one that comes to mind is a per-line protocol. ie: every line that the server sends to the client the client acknowledges and sends back an ack. which the server then processes before sending the next line. Or a per-block protocol, where the client sends say a 256KB chunk and the server acknowledges it back. or a 'ping' protocol, where you send a one-byte chunk at a given interval to make sure everything previous has been processed.

Comment: @EdwardPeschko: The variety of examples you provide for "generic" routines shows that there is actually no real generic thing but it depends on the needs of the application. It is already very different of what an application considers a "message" - in some cases it is a line, sometimes a block prefixed with a length etc. And it is pretty common that application protocols need more than just a simple ACK, but instead need information about success or status of an operation. Sending this implicitly acks the command, so why add an additonal ack?